# How to block torrents using ADSL modem?

Tags: firewall, p2p, torrent

I'm looking for a solution for a small office.

Comment: Do you mean "using an ADSL *router*"?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yours adsl modem should have integrated firewall or something like that. it will be dificult. you should block many ports and block some torrent servers. also you should use something like opendns to block most torrent sites. but thats isnt enought to block it completly.

take a point, that torrents are using hi-ports (10k+) for conenctions. so you can block em too, and punish users who are using torrents.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Not with a modem. That's not what a modem does.

Comment: Sounds real, but can you add any prooflinks?

Comment: Modems provide access to the Internet. If it doesn't have an integrated firewall, you'll need to add a machine or some other device between your switch and the modem to block access and/or track what's happening.

Comment: For the cheaper but flexible (read: has a learning curve) method, you can get a Linux or BSD box and either configure it as a firewall/proxy or boot the appliance distros available to turn it into a turnkey router.